# Equivalent of Hibernate's Restrictions.sqlRestriction in JPA2 Criteria API?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

Is there an equivalent of Hibernate's [Restrictions.sqlRestriction](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#sqlRestriction(java.lang.String)) for JPA2 Criteria API ?

Also, if there is no equivalent, I'd be interested to know if it's possible to "hack" something in Hibernate's JPA2 support to insert my own SQL snippets in the query.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such option in JPA2 (at least that I know of). You can't mix Criteria API with native SQL (or with JPAQL for that matter). The closest thing you get in JPA2 is making a native SQL query, and declaring to what Entity class(es) the response should be marshalled to, giving you effectively the posibility to make detailed SQL requests but still profit from ORM features:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JPA/UsingNamedNativeQuery.htm

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found a way to do this using JPA functions. This is hibernate 6 specific to get the SQL of the function to render without parentheses. In this case, the native SQL needs to return a list of IDs.

```
    public Expression createIdListFunction( CriteriaBuilder cb, String nativeQuery )
    {
            Expression exp = cb.function( nativeQuery, Long.class );
            SelfRenderingSqmFunction sexp = (SelfRenderingSqmFunction) exp;
            SqmFunctionDescriptor sdesc = sexp.getFunctionDescriptor();
            FieldUtils.setProtectedFieldValue( "useParenthesesWhenNoArgs", sdesc, false );
            return exp;
    }

    CriteriaBuilder cb = getCurrentSession( ).getCriteriaBuilder( );
            CriteriaQuery<Login> criteriaQuery = cb.createQuery( Login.class );
            Root<Login> root = criteriaQuery.from( Login.class );
            List<Predicate> expressions = new ArrayList<>( );
            expressions.add( root.get( "id" ).in( this.createIdListFunction( cb, "SELECT id FROM LOGIN" ) ) );
            criteriaQuery.select( root ).where( expressions.toArray( new Predicate[ 0 ] ) );
```