# is there a way to achieve Restrictions.sqlRestriction in CriteriaQuery<>

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = getSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Test> query = builder.createQuery(Test.class);
Root<Test> root = query.from(Test.class);
```

Now i came across a situation where i need to add sqlRestriction. Earlier i have used it like this with Criteria API,

```
.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction(
```

But not sure how to do it using CriteriaQuery, I have searched alot about this on internet but no luck...
Anyone knows if it is possible to achieve this or not ?
If possible, please guide me
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See the answer I posted here: [Equivalent of Hibernate's Restrictions.sqlRestriction in JPA2 Criteria API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182701/equivalent-of-hibernates-restrictions-sqlrestriction-in-jpa2-criteria-api/77927226#77927226)

We had very complex queries being dynamically generated and I did not want to have to replace them with criteria based sub queries.